# How to config cassandra in application.yml of spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, yaml

I have 'application.properties' file in Spring boot project, which have Cassandra datasource config :

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=quangkeyspace
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
```

I want to try using application.yml instead. How can I convert it? Ex:

```
data:    
   cassandra:
       keyspace-name:quangkeyspace
       contact-points:localhost
       port: 9042
       schema-action=create if not exists
```

Where can I find these keywords?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find commons spring props here :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

I would suggest to try this :

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspaceName: quangkeyspace
      contactPoints: localhost
      port: 9042
      schemaAction: CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
```

Hyphen separated keywords are generally replaced with camel case syntax.